# Group By first day of month and join with a separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL
one with monthly sales targets:

```
Date     Target
1/7/17   50000
1/8/17   65000
1/9/17   50000
1/10/17  48000
etc...
```

the other with sales orders:

```
TxnDate   JobNum    Value
3/7/17    100001   20000
3/7/17    100002   11000
8/7/17    100003   10000
10/8/17   100004   15000
15/9/17   100005   20000
```

etc...
what I want is a table with following:

```
Date    Target    Sales
1/7/17  50000    41000
1/8/17  65000    15000
1/9/17  50000    20000
```

please help me I'm a newbie to coding and this is doing my head in.. :)

Comment: Which **`RDBMS`**??

Comment: Is `Sales` same as `Value`?

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle? What are you using?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. Could you clarify a bit: what do you mean by first day of the month? (just the month?) What is this new Sales column in the result?

Comment: SQL Server, and yes sales is the same as value

Comment: @Chuck , sorry about that, yes group by month, but show the 1st day of that month in the date column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your 1st table is targetSales and your 2nd table is Sales **and** your database is SQL Server:

```
select 
    t.date
    , t.target
    , isnull(sum(s.value), 0) as Sales
from targetSales t
    left join Sales s
        on (month(t.date) = month(s.date)
            and year(t.date) = year(s.date))
group by t.date
    , t.target
```

You can follow a similar approach if you use a different database, just find the equivalents of `month()` and `year()` functions for your RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select tb1.date,tb1.target,tb2.value from table1 as tb1
INNER JOIN (select sum(value) as sales, date from table2 group by date) as tb2 
on tb1.date = tb2.date,
```

you can use this script for daily targets

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution but this will give you a correct result.

```
select date,target,(
    select sum(value) 
    from sales_orders s 
    where datepart(m,s.TxnDate) = datepart(m,targets.Date) 
    and datepart(year,s.TxnDate) = datepart(year,targets.Date)
) as sales 
from targets
```

Answer (score 0):

An another way around, looks like in `target` table the date is always the first day of the month. So in the `sales` table, just round the `TxnDate` column value to first day of the month.

**Query**

```
select t1.[date],
max(t1.[target]) as [target],
coalesce(sum(t2.[value]), 0) as [value]
from [targets] t1
left join [sales] t2
on t1.[Date] = dateadd(day, - datepart(day, t2.[txnDate]) + 1, t2.[txnDate])
group by t1.[Date];
```

**[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c76d2e/1)**

Answer (score 0):

If you take any datetime value in SQL Server, calculate the number of months from that date to zero `datediff(month,0,TxnDate)`  then add that number of moths to zero `dateadd(month, ... , 0)` you get the first day of the month for the original datetime value. This works in all versions of SQL Server. With this we can sum the values of the orders by the first day of the month, then join to targets using that date.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Orders
>     ([TxnDate] datetime, [JobNum] int, [Value] int)
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO Orders
>     ([TxnDate], [JobNum], [Value])
> VALUES
>     ('2017-07-03 00:00:00', 100001, 20000),
>     ('2017-07-03 00:00:00', 100002, 11000),
>     ('2017-07-08 00:00:00', 100003, 10000),
>     ('2017-08-10 00:00:00', 100004, 15000),
>     ('2017-09-15 00:00:00', 100005, 20000)
> ;
>
> CREATE TABLE Targets
>     ([Date] datetime, [Target] int)
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO Targets
>     ([Date], [Target])
> VALUES
>     ('2017-07-01 00:00:00', 50000),
>     ('2017-08-01 00:00:00', 65000),
>     ('2017-09-01 00:00:00', 50000),
>     ('2017-10-10 00:00:00', 48000)
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 9 rows affected
> ```

> ```
>     select dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,TxnDate), 0) month_start, sum(Value) SumValue
>     from Orders
>     group by dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,TxnDate), 0)
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> month_start         | SumValue
> :------------------ | -------:
> 01/07/2017 00:00:00 |    41000
> 01/08/2017 00:00:00 |    15000
> 01/09/2017 00:00:00 |    20000
> ```

> ```
> select
>        t.[Date], t.Target, coalesce(o.SumValue,0)
> from targets t
> left join (
>     select dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,TxnDate), 0) month_start, sum(Value) SumValue
>     from Orders
>     group by dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,TxnDate), 0)
>     ) o on t.[Date] = o.month_start
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Date                | Target | (No column name)
> :------------------ | -----: | ---------------:
> 01/07/2017 00:00:00 |  50000 |            41000
> 01/08/2017 00:00:00 |  65000 |            15000
> 01/09/2017 00:00:00 |  50000 |            20000
> 10/10/2017 00:00:00 |  48000 |                0
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8348cd31a345eb3d11a4c03e4a0df04d)*